# Make Div as wide as it needs to be

Tags: css

To explain my problem, I'm trying to make a div wide enough to accommodate a dynamically generated title without wrapping it, but the div also has other content, which I want to wrap.

In other words:

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    min-width:170px;
}

.box span.title {
    font-size:24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.box span.text{
    font-size:10px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
   <span class="title">Title on one line</span><br />
   <span class="text">This is the main body of text which I want to wrap as
           required and have no effect on the width of the div.</span>
</div>
```

However, this is causing the div to expand to be wide enough to contain the main body of text on one line, which I want to wrap.  I've tried various arrangements for CSS and the putting them all inside container divs and the like but I can't seem to get the box to be exactly wide enough to contain only the title without wrapping (but not less than the min width)

Is there any way to do this just in CSS?  Note I don't want to set a max width as this just causes it to become a static size again, as the main body of text is always going to be enough to hit the max width.  I also can't line break the body manually as it's dynamically generated.

Comment: Cant you use a table for this? one wrap and 1 no-wrap row?

Comment: @Hans no tables for layout. You are lucky comments can't be downvoted.

Comment: @Ryan see the **[XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).**

Comment: a title and text below it are tabular data in a way. At least I wouldnt be afraid to use it in this case. Especially since it works fine here

Comment: Well, you could use jQuery to compute the width of the title and use that to set the width of the box. It's a bit like using a sledgehammer to swat flies, though.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or something as to what you want your desired effect to be?

Comment: Why should one need JS for such a simple task?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Is [this (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/mjisrawi/4d5WR/17/) what you're trying to accomplish?

I just added `display: table;` to .box's CSS. This expands the main div to the width of the title span but wraps the text span.

Note: You can also set a constant width to prevent the div from expanding to the width of the window. This way it will still expand to the width of the title if it is larger than your constant width, but will not grow if the user drags out the window. In my example I added `width: 100px;` to demonstrate.

Comment: I regret that I have but one vote to give to this solution. Bravo.

Comment: In chrome this is just expanding to the width of the window, not constrained by the width of the title.

Comment: @jeroen It doesn't shrink down. It EXPANDS to larger titles.

Comment: @kingjiv it's working fine for me in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox

Comment: Using chrome 13, if you expand the window size larger than the title the text continues to the edge of the screen.

Comment: @kingjiv that can be remedied by adding something like width: 100; this way it will never be smaller than 100px, but will always grow to exactly the width of the title span. No matter the width of the browser window. I'll updated my answer to say that.

Comment: +1 Nice, setting an unrealistic width; reminds me of the 99% width settings when using tables years ago :-)

Comment: Cool! @jeroen, haha yeah I know what I mean. I guess you can look at it as if you're setting a minimum width to preserve appearances. An article with a one word title would look pretty bad if the div could shrink to any arbitrary size. :)

Comment: @mjisrawi Yep, that's exactly the effect I wanted :)  I was already manipulating the display property with jquery (the div is actually a tooltip) so I just had to change display:block to display:table and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

A working jQuery example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8AFcv/

```
$(function() {
    $(".box").width($(".title").width());
})
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I make no claims about this being the best solution. As I said above, it's using a sledgehammer to swat a fly. But it works with no side effects.

Comment: While javascript and jquery were not mentioned, this does appear to be the only working solution (except perhaps the other similar jquery solution).

Comment: Oh, and please note that I'm using class names, just as Ryan did, so if there's more than one `box` and `title` it will give unexpected results. IDs would be preferable: http://jsfiddle.net/8AFcv/1/

Answer (score 2):

For headlines you should use the `<hN>` tags (`<h1>`, `<h2>` etc).

For no text wrap:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

On the element who's text you don't want to wrap.

**[Working Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/LVk7w/)**

Comment: That doesn't do what he wants at all, the heading goes way outside the box and the box stays a static 300px.

Comment: This is called the [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341), what he (probably) wants, is for the header to no wrap, and for the text to wrap, so he figured, I'll just make the div wide and narrow at the same time! However, that is not the proper solution for the initial problem. **This one is**. :)

Comment: THIS IS the correct solution—just leave out the 300px-width and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/LVk7w/1/ @kingjiv "it looks terrible" Maybe because it's an example in a frame that is less then a fourth of the available screen size…

Comment: Of course it is, it is intensified to show the result, obviously the actual website display will be much more subtle. The example is meant to be extreme to show the difference clearly.

Comment: No it´s not, if the title is less than 100% of the containing block it does not work, the OP wants the whole box to have a specified minimum width OR the exact width of the title if it´s more.

Comment: @feeela no, that does not do what the question is asking either.  See mjisrawi's jquery example for the intended result.  The content should be constrained to the width of the title.

Comment: @jeroen Then for goods sake, add a min-width… [at]kingjiv there is no jQuery example by mjisrawi, there is one by Sergey Volosevich, which does exactly the same as the answer by Rikudo Sennin, but using unnecessary JS…

Comment: @feeela just make the title longer than the min-width but shorter than the containing box and you will see that the box still expands to 100% width: http://jsfiddle.net/LVk7w/4/ (your fiddle, title changed)

Comment: @feeela sorry copied the wrong name.  mblase75 is what I meant, and it does not do the same thing as riku's solution.  Riku's solution has a title which is around twice as wide as the content (in chrome).  I think in old versions of IE this would work, having the container expand, in chrome at least riku's solution has a title which goes 400px outside of a 300px box

Comment: Well, you don't have read my initial comment: "just leave out the 300px-width"

Comment: @feeela A div with no width has a 100% width which is not what he wants.  See mblase75's fiddle for the desired effect.

Comment: @kingjiv Your div is not expanding to contain the title - the title is going over the edge of the div.

Comment: @feeela Your div is simply 100% of the width available to it, it is not constrained by the width of the title span.

Comment: @Ryan I think you meant Riku, I didn't post a solution.

Comment: @Ryan yes, that's the point. It's usually pointless to change the width of the div in cases like this, since you only want one element to not wrap, it's probably best if it breaks out of the box, this allows your box to maintain proper width and allow more options for layout.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your correctly you can easily set the same width for yours text as for yours title using JS or jQuery, for ex:

```
$('.text').width($('.title').width())
```

and run it at jQuery(document).ready or by event if you add it dynamically

Comment: The effect could be accomplished with CSS alone.

Comment: Upvoted because it was the first reasonable (javascript...) solution, but please note that it won´t work exactly like this as you are setting the width of a span and you can only set the width of block-level elements.

Answer (score 0):

Block elements such as divs extend as far as content pushes them, unless specified by explicit widths or heights.

A pure CSS solution for this is unlikely without setting a max-width on the div.

A pointer on CSS:

- Don't include the tags in your selectors (i.e. `tag.class`) as you are then forced to use that tag with that class. Simply using `.class` will make it easier to change your markup (should you need to) as well as make your class extend its use to more than a single tag.