# How can I make an underline some pixels longer than the headline?

Tags: css

I am currently trying to make a custom underline with border-bottom. However, currently the underline is going all the way of my block-element (whole page).

I’d prefer to have it being only 50px longer than my headline (however the text is flexible and I do not know the length).

Can I do this without adding another `<span>` tag within the `<h2>` somehow? I do not wannt to add a `<span>` element to each `<h2>` just to change my design.

Current HTML is:

```
<h1>My title</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #b62525;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c68181;
}
```

Is it possible to adjust the border-bottom length to my text length? (e.g. behave like inline element for border, but like block for newlines, padding and margin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block` works, the only caveat being that the content after the `<h1>` tag must be the full width of the container element. The other solutions here also assume this. You can also use `display: inline` (supported by older browsers), but `inline-block` allows for setting of explicit widths, should you need it.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez6G3/4/)

#### CSS

```
h1
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #888;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inline or floating methods can be problematic if you're unable to compensate for them in other rules. One alternative is to use [display:table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231430/make-div-as-wide-as-it-needs-to-be)

```
h1
{
        display:table;
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
        padding-right:50px;
}
```

Comment: Is it good style to set display: table on a block element? As for <table> web designers came to the conclusion, that it’s only for tabular content and not for design. What about display: table?

Comment: Just to note, `display: table` isn't supported by [IE7 and below](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
  h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #b62525;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #c68181;
        float: left;
        padding-right: 50px
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add one more property in css like this :

```
h1 {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #b62525;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c68181;
}
```