# CSS force line break on container extension

Tags: html, css

**What i have:**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">
        Some long text
    </div>
    <div class="extendable">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    float: right;
    min-width: 10em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    .text {
        padding: 0.3em;
    }
}
```

Every block has dynamic width and height.
http://jsfiddle.net/vZ4eA/

**What i want:**
`.text` shouldn't be able to extend `.container` if the content gets too big. There should be a forced line break.
`.extendable` on the other hand should make `container` bigger if the content exceeds the width (behave normally).

Comment: in case the `.container` gets wide, do you want the `.text` to also get wider to fill it horizontally?

Comment: @Ejay yes `.text` should extend aswell if `.container` gets really wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a fixed width on `.text` and then use `word-break:break-all;`

Using jQuery you can set the width of `.text` to be that of `.extendable`.

```
 var exWidth = $('.extendable').css('width');
 $('.text').css('width', exWidth);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vZ4eA/16/

**Edit: CSS Only**

You could try placing `.text` inside `.extendable`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vZ4eA/18/

**EDIT 2: CSS:**

With some help from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7231607/1399670 I have updated the fiddle to match your requirements.

http://jsfiddle.net/vZ4eA/20/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `max-width` for the text along with `nowrap`

```
.text{
padding: .3em;
border: 1px solid red;
max-width: 200px;
word-break: break-all;
display: block;

}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vZ4eA/8/)

**EDIT:**

To respond to one of the comments below, the `max-width` should probably be a *dynamic* value in order to work with the dynamic width of the container. You could easily implement this behavior with `javascript` or `jQuery`

**jQuery**

I recommend you check out [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) to handle the re-sizing of your `div`

```
$("#div").resize(function(e){
    $(".text").css({"max-width" : $(this).css("max-width") });
});
```

Comment: Then it will still extend if `.container` is smaller than this max width and won't if `.extendable` is bigger than that.

Comment: @NikoM. I've edited, is this what you wanted? If not please let me know.

Comment: The result is surely what i wanted. The thing is, that i do not want to use javascript for initial styling adjustments. Especially for simple stuff like that...

Comment: @NikoM. You don't need to use javascript to style, only to dynamically change. There is no way around that ...

Comment: If there is a way around it or not depends if i can manage to find a css solution for the desired behaviour. I am currently trying some things out with the Attributes `display` `position` and `float`. If i cannot find a solution and there is no CSS geek comming up with a workaround i guess i will have to go with the js solution. I don't like such 'dirty' coding though...

Comment: @NikoM. Using `js` is not an *ugly* solution by any means. It may be different to what you're used to, but nearly every website today uses js to handle dynamic CSS.

Comment: If there is no other way around it is fine, i agree, but you also wouldn't set a fixed height for a text-block and then change it with javascript if it exceeds it, would you?

Answer (score 0):

The only method I can think applicable here would be to set max-width on .text

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to dynamically update the max-width of .text as .container resizes; specifically, on page load, and on viewport resize. You can do this [using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery).